# How can I make a div expand on click with only one open at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, expand

As shown in here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/03/accordion-madness. But I need help to edit it so that it will work for my circumstances.

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="row even">
<div class="info">
  <div class="class">CK1</div>
  <div class="teacher_chinese">老師</div>
  <div class="teacher_english">Teacher Name</div>
  <div class="assistant_chinese">助教</div>
  <div class="assistant_english">Assistant Name</div>
  <div class="room">Room 00</div>
  <div class="book"></div>
</div>
<div class="chapters">
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=1"><span class="chapter">一</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=2"><span class="chapter">二</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=3"><span class="chapter">三</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=4"><span class="chapter">四</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=5"><span class="chapter">五</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=6"><span class="chapter">六</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=7"><span class="chapter">七</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=8"><span class="chapter">八</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=9"><span class="chapter">九</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=10"><span class="chapter">十</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=11"><span class="chapter">十一</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=12"><span class="chapter">十二</span></a>
  <a href="../../curriculum/cantonese/textbook.php?cls=C1&amp;ch=13"><span class="chapter">十三</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY [Work In Progress]**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div#table_cantonese .chapters').hide();
$('div#table_cantonese .book').click(function() {
  var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
  var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');
  if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
    $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
      $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
    });
  } else {
    $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
  }
}); 
});
```

So when the end-user click on div.book, div.chapters will expand. And only one div.chapters will be shown at a time. So if a div.chapters is already open, then it will close the open one first before animating the one the user clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually there are a couple obvious ways to achieve this.

1. You could try keeping a handle to
   the div which should be opened at
   this very moment.  When a new div is
   selected, first hide the opened div,
   then open the new div and assign the
   currently open handle to the now
   opened div.
2. Make it so that when you click on
   any, it just closes all divs no
   matter what, then opens just the div
   that was selected.
3. ...

The trick to it is that just about all of these techniques are made simple by applying your javascript to the parent of all the divs which should behave when selected.

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable to store the previously opened DIV. Then when a new DIV is opened, close the previously opened one.

```
var prev=false;

//...

if(prev!==false)
    // close prev
prev = new_div;
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a global variable if you can avoid it. I'd go with `(function(){var prev = false; $(document).ready(/*stuff that needs prev */);})()`